# How to add a simple autcomplete feature in a form without using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to create a form for my user which shows a drop down list of 10 elements/strings(which I can provide without making use of Ajax) and all I want is that the list should pop down when the user tries to fill the form and allow the user to add an element/string from the drop down list...

I have seen the autocomplete plugin of jquery, but it is packed with a lot more features that I won't be using and also because it is too heavy... I am looking for a plugin that's light and just fits my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) has [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). It doesn't required ajax. Just an array of strings initialized on load. From the jQuery UI website

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

The jQuery UI plugins come to a total of 38KB for this feature.

Answer (score 3):

use [jquery ui autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = //array of strings
    $("#example").autocomplete(data); //example is id of input element
  });
```

**UPDATE**:: You can customize jQuery UI while [downloading](http://jqueryui.com/download) optimized for autocomplete only.

Comment: The second paragraph says he doesn't want to use jQuery.

Comment: ... because it is "too heavy". Loading *just* autocomplete (well, plus the UI core) wouldn't be (or at least, it's not supposed to be).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two articles showing pure Javascript (no jQuery) methods for auto-complete:

Simple solution using a text box with `<select>` list for storing/displaying choices:
http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column5/

More complicated sample offering more customisation (includes blur/focus/mouse event handlers):
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Javascript-AutoComplete/